# CSS3 Ken Burn effect pause when the page is scrolling then play again for smooth animation

Tags: css, effects, css-transitions, css-animations

I have built a CSS3 Ken Burn effect with the aid of others in this community. It was jerky until we switched to a translating animation. Now it is very smooth.

http://jsfiddle.net/gxUhH/52/

The problem now is that when the page is scrolled on a touch screen device, it then becomes jerky. Presumably this is from the additional processing power required.

I think the solution would be to pause the animation on scroll and then play again after scroll has complete. I do not know how to accomplish this. I'd also enjoy hearing any other suggestions on the matter.

The fiddle above will show you it all functional. WebKit only at the moment.

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Answer (score 1):

I had some issues with flickering and jerky animations and this bit fixed it up:

```
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```